# IN different aspects or ON different aspects

Tags: prepositions

Which is more accurate:
"He can significantly contribute to the company IN different aspects"
Or
"He can significantly contribute to the company ON different aspects"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different meanings to the adverbial phrase when changing between these prepositions.

> He can contribute in different aspects.

This means that there are many ways that his contribution can be given.  Perhaps he is an authority on digital systems AND he's great friends with your supply chain.  Because of this, his contributions come in many different forms.

> He can contribute on different aspects.

This means there are multiple facets of the company that require assistance.  The quality or type of contribution is not necessarily changing, just the direction in which it is aimed.

Either way, my final advice on use would be to scrap the phrase entirely.  It is perhaps a bit of a vague sentence and could be regarded as filler depending on its intended use.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Test your core structures at Google Books:

"contribute on various aspects" [a bit strange, and rare

8 results

"contribute in various aspects" [correct, but rare

9 results

Cf.

["contribute **in** various **ways**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contribute%20to%20the%20company%20IN%20various%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22contribute%20IN%20various%20ways%22)

**About 29,100 results**

Now you're talking :-)

Also:

"different" --> "various"